# Element gets pushed to the right. Why?

Tags: android, xml, admob

When my `LinearLayout` is coded like this:

```
<LinearLayout ...
<!-- SOME CODE HERE -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="17">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/inputText"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters|textMultiLine"
        android:hint="@string/input_text_hint"
        android:gravity="top|left"/>
</LinearLayout>
<!-- MORE CODE HERE -->
</LinearLayout>
```

My activity looks like this:
[image]

But when I add this adMob code:

```
<LinearLayout ...
<!-- SOME CODE HERE -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="17">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/top_banner_1">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/inputText"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters|textMultiLine"
        android:hint="@string/input_text_hint"
        android:gravity="top|left"/>
</LinearLayout>
<!-- MORE CODE HERE -->
</LinearLayout>
```

I get this:
[image]

How do I get the ad to be on top of the `EditText`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default orientation for a LinearLayour is horizontal, which makes the add pushing your EditText to the right. If you add `android:orientation="vertical"` to your parent LinearLayout the issue is solved.

I think that the correct code you have to use is:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_weight="17">

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/top_banner_1">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/inputText"
    android:inputType="textCapCharacters|textMultiLine"
    android:hint="@string/input_text_hint"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have removed some properties that can make your layout look ugly in the image you provided.